# Graphicall shell for Haskell under Linux

Tags: linux, shell, haskell, user-interface

Is there some graphical shell like ghci for Haskell and Linux? I know about Winghci and it is very good interpreter but it is Windows only.

Comment: Uh... ghci runs on linux too. It's a standard part of the GHC packages in all distributions.

Comment: What's the big difference between Winghci and ghci in a terminal?

Comment: @DanielFischer  GUI version is far more convenient is also supports some key bindings like ctrl+e to open editor and ctrl+r to reload file -- to do this in ghci you must punch commands in.

Comment: In ghci, `:e` and `:r` do it (you need to configure the editor to make `:e` work, but that's only once). I can believe Winghci offers (much) more than that, I just don't know what it offers. While ctrl+r is just two keystrokes vs. three (or four, if `:` needs shift) for :+r+return, I wouldn't consider that a big difference. If that were all, I'd say "so what?". But, if you can live with emacs or vim as editor, they have pretty good (I hear) ghci integration packages.

Comment: @Trismegistos Does winGHCi actually come with any feature that GHCi doesn't provide out of the box? Whether you type ctrl+e or shift+.,e,return isn't such a huge difference (I don't think you open your editor often enough to make the half a second overhead significant). I used winghci only very briefly, but I can't say I'm missing anything in ghci (if anything, I find it more convenient to run ghci in terminal).

Comment: @DanielFischer You may configure editor for ghci by setting environmental variable -- which is not ideal because you set editor for all applications -- besides in super inconvenient because ghci runs editor  and blocks input into console while Winghci can run editor in background.

Comment: You can also set the editor in your `.ghci` with a `:set editor <cmd>` line. The not-in-the-background thing is indeed inconvenient, however. I suppose it's possible to overcome that by writing a wrapper for the editor invocation, but it's probably easier to go the other way, invoking ghci from the editor. Or do it as I do and have editor and ghci independent. Switching is just Alt+tab or a mouse-click. (Until somebody writes a thing like Winghci for Linux.)

Comment: Yep, it's possible. Just write a shell script that invokes the editor with the passed arguments as a background process and set that script as your editor command.

Comment: I know it is possible and even simple but again inconvenient because you have to store this script somewhere  so most probably you will have some additional bin folder messing your home directory and I like mine as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "what does WinGHCi do that GHCi does not?":

- The command prompt, user input and program output are different colours. I can't *begin* to tell you how helpful this is when you're scrolling through huge pages of text trying to find the last command you typed. I wish more Haskell programs would produce coloured output...
- You can load files using an actual GUI, rather than having to memorise a 200-mile long file path.
- It has a whole bunch of buttons and menu items for common operations, which can be useful if you're new to GHCi and don't know the corresponding command names.
- On Windows, terminal windows look *horrifyingly ugly*, while WinGHCi does not. Whether this problem exists on Linux is a matter of opinion.

Regarding the *actual question asked*: I'm not aware of any nice GUI tool for GHCi on Linux. Probably the best you can do is use the Emacs operating system; I'm *sure* somebody will have built some kind of GHCi support for that by now...

Answer (score 1):

ghci runs fine on Linux, although I don't know of any graphical versions of it.

A few options if you want more features:

1. Use a powerful terminal emulator
2. Integrate ghci into your editor with something like 'Emacs Haskell Mode' or 'SHIM for Vim'

Comment: Dedicated solution like e.g. winghci is more adjusted and allows to do many things you can not do with simple command line interpreted. GUI environment is also more user-friendly even though I use terminal on daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of HUGS ? I only used it for Windows, but on the [website](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/downloading.htm) you can download it for some Linux distributions, too. 
It's a long time ago since I used it, but as far as I can remember it was an easy to use but powerful and fairly good documented interpreter.

hope this helps

Comment: Hugs is, unfortunately, basically dead. Last release in 2006.

Comment: really? that's a pity, I liked it (well when I used it years ago :)

Comment: Yes, it was nice. But no use crying over spilled milk, and ghci comes even with a full-blown compiler :)

Comment: OK, I am convinced, now :) ghci sounds pretty cool, especially that debugger.